# How is this Antenna Plug Type Called?

Tags: connector, antenna, adapter, pcb-antenna

For a project, I would like to connect a cheap PCB antenna from Molex to a SMA female connector. One of the antenna is this one:

Molex 146220-0100:
http://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/1462200100_ANTENNAS.xml

[image]

Instead of a exact description of the connector of the antenna, the specs only state that it fits on a "Microcoaxial RF" connector, described as: 50 Ohms, MCRF, PCB Vertical Jack Receptacle, SMT, 1.25mm Mounted Height. Shown here: http://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/0734120110_RF_COAX_CONNECTORS.xml

[image]

**Is the plug on the antenna a proprietary connector from Molex?**

Or in the other case, whats the right name of the connector I have to search for?

My goal is to find an adapter from the connector of this antenna to the SMA female connector on the board I use.

Comment: "Is the plug on the antenna a proprietary connector from Molex?" have you tried asking Molex this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are commonly and informally known as "U.FL connectors" after the original part number from Hirose, see this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirose_U.FL.

It is a proprietary connector from Hirose, but many second source exist, typically under the name "ultraminiature coaxial connector" or similar.

Search for "UFL to SMA".